# Сохранить содержимое консоли в файл. Java

Tags: java, консоль

Возможно ли как-то это осуществить?
 Например, программа сработала, консоль отобразила результат и пользователь введя букву "s" переносит всё содержимое консоли в .txt файл.

Comment: Под содержимым консоли вы имеет ввиду то, что ваша программа в неё выводила?

Comment: не проще ли не считывать из консоли, а сразу записывать в переменные то, что должно было выводиться?

Comment: вроде бы неделю-две назад был похожий вопрос: как прочитать всё, что программа выводила. найти не смог

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, да

Comment: @michael_best, там выводится не одна переменная, а результат вызова нескольких методов: текст и матрицы и т.д. Всё это нужно как-то сохранить в файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import org.apache.commons.io.output.TeeOutputStream;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        OutputStream teeStream = new TeeOutputStream(System.out, buffer);
        // После этой строки любой вывод будет сохраняться в buffer
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(teeStream));

        // Выводим в консоль строку
        System.out.println("Hello World!");

        // Сохраняем buffer в файл
        try(OutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream("console.txt")) {
            buffer.writeTo(fileStream);
        }
        // В console.txt теперь строка "Hello World!"
    }
}
```

Comment: Извините, но у меня почему-то ругается на writeTo(fileStream). Пишет cannot find symbol. Подключал библиотеку commons-io-2.6.jar

Comment: @SergeyStashkevich мой косяк, слишком сузил абстракцию. Исправил ответ, проверьте.

Comment: Да, теперь работает, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Сделать это возможно. Я бы через java.io написал таким образом:

```
import java.io.*;

 public class Solution
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(reader.readLine());

    while (true)
    {
        String data = reader.readLine();
        if(data.equals("s")){
            outputStream.write(data.getBytes());
            break;
        }
        else {
            outputStream.write((data +"\r\n").getBytes());
        }
    }
    outputStream.close();
    reader.close();
}
}
```